# How can I check if a livestream works without actually opening it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, video-streaming, vlc

So I have this basic working video player, that opens me a window and plays me the internet stream using this code:

```
import vlc
Instance = vlc.Instance('--play-and-exit')
player = Instance.media_player_new()
Media = Instance.media_new("http://url.to/whateverLivestream")
Media.get_mrl()

player.set_media(Media)
player.play()
```

But I would like the script just to check if the livestream exists and WOULD be playing if I wanted to open it WITHOUT actually opening it.

How can I do that?

Thanks a lot!

[Edit:]
Now it's been 4 months and I still could not solve the problem. I would like to add to this thread, that I do not care whether this gets solved with the VLC plugin or any other one. ANY solution (python-based) is fine!

Comment: Possible duplicate/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38772208/693052 a bash script verifying if vlc's state is 'playing' - maybe this points you in the right direction?

Comment: Well the question seems certainly similar, but I want to solve it in Python. Kind of in a way like I open a Website and it doesn't exist and gives me an HTTPError Exception. Unfortunately if I try to open an invalid livestream link, I get no Exception. The video player just does not open and no error message.